# Batchfile to rename files

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, variables, rename

Sadly I couldn't yet manage find a working solution but hopefully this time.
Long story short, we got a printer and we are currently unable to configure the scanfolder to our network drives. So I need a script to rename and move the files but keep them all.

As far as I managed to come I got a smart idea to move the files into a firstfolder to avoid that the files are overwritten. Next I need to either rename the files with a counter or move them and keep them all.

I choose the rename option since this seems more simple but I ran into one big issue.

I have no idea how I make it work. So what I'm trying is to first set the variable and do a first test calculation. Just for a first quick test. Now it already works for the first count but sadly it doesn't count up as hoped since he does the rename for all the files before increasing the value of the variable so only one file is renamed.

```
@ECHO off
::Defining Variables
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET N=0
ECHO %N% Hi Not rename
SET /a N=%N%+1
FOR /L %%A in (1,1,10) DO (
    Echo !N! hi
    RENAME "C:\Users\smorheng\Desktop\1\*.pdf" "Test.?????.!N!.*" | SET /a N=!N!+1
    ECHO !N! Hi Not rename
    timeout 3 /nobreak > nul
)
ECHO RENAME DONE
timeout 50 /nobreak > nul
```

About 20 Files are renamed to something like Test.1.pdf, Test.2.pdf .... Test.20.pdf and then moved to their destination.

The moving is not an issue but if I could manage to get this feature working I can adapt it to whatever I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply move the files, but first check if the file exists in destination, if it does, rename it using a numeric value after the name. Here is something that might work. You just need to change source and destination folder below. The actual move will not occur as I added `echo` to the second last and last line to demonstrate what it will do, if it works, simply remove echo from both lines.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "source=C:\Users\smorheng\Desktop\1\"
set "dest=D:\destination\folder"
set /a cnt=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /S /B /A-D "%source%*.pdf"') do for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('dir /B "%%a"') do if exist "%dest%\%%b" (
        set "ext=%%~xa"
        set "fname=%%~na"
        if exist "%dest%\!fname!(!cnt!)!ext!" (set /a cnt=!cnt!+1)
        set /a cnt=!cnt!+1
        echo move "%%a" "%dest%\!fname!(!cnt!)!ext!"
) else echo move "%%a" "%dest%\%%b"
```

Also note, this will recursively `move` all files from within the directory tree, if you only want to go into the first directory, simply remove `/S` from the for loop which will then simply become `dir /B /A-D "%source%*.pdf"`

**Edit**
As for your `for /L` loop (mentioned in comment)

Rather have a label and permanently goto it after completed. Here is a simple example of something like that, copy it to a script and run it, see the result:

```
@echo off
:label
echo Hi, this will run every 6 seconds and print this line. (infinitely).
timeout 6>nul
goto :label
```

So technically you can do the exact same for your loop, for instance:

```
@echo off
:label
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "source=C:\Users\smorheng\Desktop\1\"
set "dest=D:\destination\folder"
set /a cnt=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /S /B /A-D "%source%*.pdf"') do for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('dir /B "%%a"') do if exist "%dest%\%%b" (
        set "ext=%%~xa"
        set "fname=%%~na"
        if exist "%dest%\!fname!(!cnt!)!ext!" (set /a cnt=!cnt!+1)
        set /a cnt=!cnt!+1
        echo move "%%a" "%dest%\!fname!(!cnt!)!ext!"
) else echo move "%%a" "%dest%\%%b"
endlocal
timeout 6>nul
goto :label
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpful piece of code. :D
It's basicly solved my whole problem. :)
Now I only need to implement it into the movement code and set the right ammount of rounds for it to run. I will try to have a deeper look into this to understand all the functions properly to not just use the code but also to understand it ;)

Comment: You do not need to run any rounds to run it, you simply need to run this, it will check file existance, and then if the file exists in the destination it will rename it before moving. You pretty much tried to do `for /l (1,1,10)...`which will do something a number of times only. This piece of code will run it for any pdf file and will move everything, including the renamed ones.

Comment: No no. This was just the last part of the script. The script actually needs to keep running at least as long as our store is open. This is why I had to add 'FOR /L %%A in (1,1,8400)' to the script with a 6 second-break because otherwise the script will run too fast and waste CPU capacities. The people also need at least 6 seconds from the scanner to their desks. So yeah this will probably work fine after a first testrun period ;)
So yeah. Thx for the help :D

Comment: but why not just create a label and goto it each time instead of having a for loop for an unknown number of runs?

Comment: It is because the users should have it as simple as possible. Believe me. As a programmer you have to make sure to think ahead and find possible issues a user might have like the question "What is this?" or "What is this for?" Don't worry. I got everything working now. ;)

Comment: ok, was just saying, a goto label will consume less CPU regardless and is really much easier, but anyhow, glad you're happy with the result.

Comment: I didn't said I won't give it a try ;)
It sure looks very interesting and very functional too :)
I found however a very big floor in my script. It just copies the PDF no matter if the transfer is done or not. No idea how I can solve this without keeping the people wait for at least a minute :/

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing "RENAME" to `SET newname` see if that helps?

*EDIT* or try a vbs script instead of a batch?

```
`Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolder="c:\test"
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)
For Each strFile In objFolder.Files
    If objFS.GetExtensionName(strFile) = "jpg" Then    
        strFileName = strFile.Name
        If InStr(strFileName,"XXXXXXX") > 0 Then           
            strNewFileName = Replace(strFileName,"XXXXX","YYYYY")
            strFile.Name = strNewFileName
        End If 
    End If  
Next `
```